# Cannot create virtual switch Hyper-V (0x80041002)

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, virtualization, hyper-v

I had a situation where a VM in Hyper-V on Win 10 Pro (build 19043.1415) wouldn´t stop and the first thing I did was stopping various services related to Hyper-V. After that I rebooted the host, and suddenly all my VM`s were no longer listed in Hyper-V.
I thought this was weird, cause usually you´d expect these services to come back after a reboot. Anyway, I tried restarting services related to Hyper-V, but they all seemed to have a dependency, unnamed, prevending them from running.
After a bit of trying to resolve it, I decided to simply uncheck Hyper-V as installed, reboot and then check it as installed + reboot again.
Now I could see my machines again, but ran into a new problem: The virtual internal switch that I use for connecting through my VPN was gone. So I tried creating it, both with Hyper-V and from PowerShell, but with the same result:

```
New-VMSwitch -Name Intern -SwitchType Internal
New-VMSwitch : Virtuelle Ethernet-switchforbindelser kunne ikke tilføjes.
Intern miniport kunne ikke oprettes. Navn = '1F870B16-E6E9-4D9E-83EC-7A114ACB9A49', brugervenligt navn = '', MAC = 'DYN
AMIC': Not found (0x80041002).
At line:1 char:1
+ New-VMSwitch -Name Intern -SwitchType Internal
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-VMSwitch], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unspecified,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.NewVMSwitch
```

Please bear with the message being in Danish, but it´s basically telling that Virtual internet switch connections could not be added and the internal miniport could not be created.
The same thing happened when trying to add an external switch. It takes up to 10 mins before I get the message btw.
I found others with what seemed to be a similar problem, but here the solution was to remove Hyper-V (in already mentioned way) and do a netcfg -d, reboot, reinstall hyper-v and reboot, but this did not make any difference for me.
I also found a quick fix from MS, that also did not improve my situation.

Some good ideas apart from reinstalling Windows?

Edit: Added list showing states of all hyper-v related services in my system.

[image: a busy cat]

Edit: Did a repair install of Win 10, but this did not solve the problem.

Edit: Did a sfc /scannow - same result.

Edit: Current output for relevant info from CoreInfo64:

```
    HYPERVISOR * Hypervisor is present 
    VMX - Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization 
    SVM - Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
```

Comment: Without knowing which services you manually turned off it will be difficult to answer this question.  The command to create a new virtual switch will obviously NOT work if the required service is not running. With regards to the service not starting, what can you tell us about that error, since the error you provided is completely and totally expected in your system's current state. Is the image in [this](https://appuals.com/hyper-v-ethernet-switch-error-windows-server-failed-to-start/) article the error in question?

Comment: Should the services not start again as per the settings after a reboot, and especially after reinstalling Hyper-V, that I would expect to reset them to their defaults? Anyway, the error showing in the article looks a lot like what I got when trying to load server from local computer before I restored Hyper-V. Maybe you can gather something from the screenshot from Process Hacker 2 I´ve added in the initial post, showing states of hyper-v services. It´s the same services I was fiddling with when it all went down.

Comment: Everything is in Danish. I don't read Danish

Comment: Sorry about that, updated the list with English equivalents.

Comment: Does CoreInfo64 indicate your system does or doesn’t support hardware virtualization.  I have a theory.

Comment: @Ramhound:

This is what you´ll want to see, I guess:

HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
SVM             -       Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization

Comment: @Ramhound: In fact I can start the virtual machines with a private switch, just not add an internal or external switch. Would this be possible without hardware virtualization enabled?

Comment: Since your comment was unformatted I miss read the information

Comment: @Ramhound: No worries, I actually wanted to format it but AFAIK I cannot do that in comments, but I may be wrong. I think this is an issue with the MAC address pool. What do you think?

Comment: @CoreyHard  - That is because you are suppose to put information like that appears in your comment in the question body.

Comment: @Ramhound: Point taken, updated the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: Unistalled Comodo Internet Security, rebooted and I could proceed with creating the switch. I did not have to do this when I created a switch a few months ago, but there´s probably a conflict between Comodo and a recent Win 10 update causing this.

Comment: Just an FYI, there's little point to running a 3rd party AV with Windows Defender in Win10+ consistently scores on par with the top rated 3rd party AVs in independent testing.

Comment: Yeah, it´s not the first time Comodo had me caught in a situation like this, so I´m considering getting rid of it for good this time. I just find that the Windows Security Package is not as user friendly, but I guess I could try to get used to it. Thanks!